# Custom class, require append string to attribute or set to array but nothing else

Tags: ruby

I have a custom class: User
I would like to allow the user to append a keyword to the attribute "keywords" or replace all keywords with an array.
I do not want to allow the user to set the attribute to a single string, or a number.

From what I've read, I think I need to create a custom setter method.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class User
    attr_accessor :username, #strings
                  :id,
                  :primary_group,
                  :first_name,
                  :last_name,
                  :full_name,
                  :home_folder,
                  :shell,
                  :email_address

    attr_reader :keywords

    def keywords=(new_keywords)
        if ( new_keywords.kind_of?(Array) )
            @keywords = new_keywords
        else
            raise ArgumentError, "'#{new_keywords}' must be an array."
        end
    end
end
```

How can I make it where the attribute "Keywords" only accepts an array? Or adding an object to the array? (It should start out as an empty array.)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You have a misspelling in this line: `if ( new_keyword.kind_of?(Array) )`

Comment: Added the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

With your code you may use it like:

```
usr = User.new
usr.keywords = %w{one two}
p usr.keywords #["one", "two"]
```

I would recommend another usage:

```
class User
    attr_reader :keywords
    def initialize()
      @keywords = []
    end
    def <<(keyword)
      raise ArgumentError, "'#{keyword}' is no string" unless keyword.is_a?(String)
      @keywords  << keyword
    end
    def reset_keywords
      @keywords = []
    end
end

usr = User.new
p usr.keywords #[]
usr << 'one'
usr << 'two'
p usr.keywords #["one", "two"]
usr.reset_keywords
p usr.keywords #[]
```

Alternative:

```
class User
    attr_reader :keywords
    def initialize()
      @keywords = []
    end
    #Add one or more keywords
    def add_keyword(*keywords)
      keywords.each{|keyword|
        raise ArgumentError, "'#{keyword}' is no string" unless keyword.is_a?(String)
        @keywords  << keyword
      }
    end
    #Alias for usage in plural
    alias :add_keywords :add_keyword
    def reset_keywords
      @keywords = []
    end
end

usr = User.new
p usr.keywords #[]
usr.add_keyword('one')
usr.add_keyword('two')
p usr.keywords #["one", "two"]
usr.reset_keywords
p usr.keywords #[]
usr.add_keywords('one', 'two')
p usr.keywords #["one", "two"]
```

Comment: Do either of these methods allow me to add keywords by using the built in array methods?

i.e. keywords.push('student'), keywords.insert(-1,'student'), keywords.pop, etc.

Comment: Just try it. And yes, a `usr.keywords.push('student')` should be possible. `usr.keywords` returns the array `@keywords` and there you have all methods you want.